# Change Button and Label position during execution

Tags: xcode

I'm bit surprised, because I'd like to change a label and a textfield in dynamic during my App execution. I mean based on an image size, I need to change label and textfield position. But, it doesn't work. 
I did all the creation in the main window file (ex xib).

Then when I'm clicking on my segment selector I'm doing this (and my field and label are nt moving !?):

```
    CGRect frame = [LHeight frame];
    frame.origin.x += 100;  // change the location
    frame.size.width += 100;  // change the size
    [LHeight setFrame:frame];
```

Even this method does't work :

```
LHeight.frame = CGRectMake(LHeight.frame.origin.x + 100, LHeight.frame.origin.y,     LHeight.frame.size.width + 100, LHeight.frame.size.height);
```

is any parameters to change in the XIB file ?

thanks in advance for your support.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
LHeight.frame = CGRectMake(LHeight.frame.origin.x + 100, LHeight.frame.origin.y, LHeight.frame.size.width + 100, LHeight.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: I found why ! It comes from Layout in the General view.

Comment: Hi user1762166, How did you achieved this?